# Trying to download homebrew

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

I'm trying to install brew

Windows 10 cmd

```
> pip install brew
```

> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/c3/3534ff8c715a34ba11a8419bb62f4ea71797b6eb314dd786d6035bcb2592/homebrew-0.1.10-py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: homebrew
>   Successfully installed homebrew-0.1.10

```
> brew install PyAudio
```

> "brew" is not an internal or external command or executable

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is an English-only site. However, there exists [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) if your preferred language is Russian.

Comment: Homebrew is typically not installed via `pip`, what you installed seems to be a homebrew wrapper under the name of `hb`. Why don't you install pyaudio via pip, i.e. `pip install pyaudio`?